# Upgrade from precise -> trusty stalls with glib critical error

Tags: upgrade

Mid way through an upgrade from precise to trusty I get the following Glib-critical error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5zft.jpg

What's the best way of recovering from this?

Comment: I ended up rebooting and starting the install using a dvd I had lying around

Answer (score -1):

First install bleachbit and clean all the junk

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit

sudo bleachbit
```

Then do the update via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo do-release-upgrade
```